# what's wrong with this assign?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am using `GMGridView` in my project. And in `- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` method, i write a snippet which is out of my expectation. The snippet is as follows:

```
if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[GMGridViewCell alloc] init];

        ThumbImageView *view = [[ThumbImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
        [view setBackgroundColor:DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR];
        [view setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        NSLog(@"view frame width:%f,height:%f",view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height);
        cell.contentView = view;
        NSLog(@"cell.contentView frame width:%f,height:%f",cell.contentView.frame.size.width,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
    }
```

when it runs the output is as follows:

```
2013-06-03 11:02:05.508 XXX[71692:707] view frame width:115.000000,height:180.000000
2013-06-03 11:02:05.511 XXX[71692:707] cell.contentView frame width:0.000000,height:0.000000
```

why assign view to cell.contentView, cell.contentView.frame.size still be zero? and also cell.contentView can display the image properly. what's the reason? I am totally confused:(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you've created new views, and you're looking at the frame of one of those views before the run loop has reached its layout phase.

When you create the `GMGridViewCell`, it starts with a default `frame` and `bounds` of `CGRectZero`.  When you set its content view, it sets the content view's `frame` to its (the cell's) `bounds`.  So even though you set the content view's frame directly using `initWithFrame:`, the frame gets changed to `CGRectZero` when you set the view as the cell's content view.

Since the cell isn't a subview of the grid view yet, there's no way to ask the grid view to lay out the cell by the time you're trying to log the content view's frame.  If the grid view is using a constant size for all cells, and you know what that size is, you could manually set the cell to that size before setting the cell's content view.  Otherwise, you need to wait until after the grid view's `layoutSubviews` method has run to check the content view's frame.

Answer (score 3):

Check [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **contentView**
>
> Returns the content view of the cell object. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView *contentView`

contentView is a readonly property. You can't assign it.

Comment: I see, but i'm using GMGridView, in my GMGridViewCell the contentView is like this @property (nonatomic, strong) ThumbImageView   *contentView;